# Is there a way to convert HTML back to character in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to convert HTML back to character in R. For example

```
v1 <- "This is the link <a href=https://google.com>Click here</a> also there is another link, <a href=https://yahoo.com>Click here</a>"
```

Expected output

```
"This is the link https://google.com also there is another link, https://yahoo.com"
```

Comment: Do you want to get the inner text of the html, or links in `href`? From your expected output it is not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: No no. Just the texts. No links :)

Comment: Well, there's a link in your expected output.

Comment: No no. its just plain texts . ````"This is the link https://google.com also there is another link, https://yahoo.com"````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to remove the text that you don't want.

```
gsub("<a href=(.*?)>.*?</a>", "\\1 ",v1)

#[1] "This is the link https://google.com  also there is another link, https://yahoo.com "
```

This removes everything except the link between every `<a>..</a>` tags.

Comment: Thanks. I do not need "Click here" also?

Comment: Sure, I missed it. See the updated answer.